# External config file that still allows changes after pyinstaller compile to exe?

Tags: python, config, external

I'm still learning, and trying to understand how all of this works....
I made a script and It has some User configurable things that get stored in a separate `config.py` file.

when I run the script, it Imports the Variables from that `config.py` file.
if I compile it with pyinstaller, It then no longer looks externally for it
my end user needs to be able to update the config on the fly to change what certain variables do

its for sorting and organizing some data, so one user might have

```
variable1 = ('data1','data2','data3')
```

another user might need to add a `data4` or remove a `data2` from that list to customize it to what their task is

how do I make it so that after the main portion of the script is compiled, I can still have an editable configuration file that the end user can change the variables

-Edited to show what I have already going on

This is the current config file I use...it is called SortingConfig.py
and I access it in the main script with this line in the beginning of the file

from SortingConfig import *

```
####   Fill in your Details Below

####   Format within each set of () should look as Follows
####   ('Item 1' , 'Item 2' , 'Item 3')
####   Words that use an ' in the name such as L'Acoustics
####   Need to be Formatted as ('L\'Acoustics)
####   Using the Product Code instead of the Product Description 
####   can solve alot of problems created by Product Descriptions with an ' in them


#L1 Category to Keep
l1cat=('Audio Terminal', 'Communications/Telephone', 'Microphones', 'Speakers')


#Category to Remove
cat=('Audio Snakes', 'Speaker Accessories', 'Mic Accessories', 'W Coupler Cables')

#If Item appears in L1 / Category / Product Code / Product Description, Color it
#Formatting = (['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'])


#Color 1
color01=('00FCC84E')
cat1=(['Speakers','Atlas Mic Stands'])

#Color 2
color02=('00ABFF6B')
cat2=(['Audio Mixers/Console'])

#Color 3
color03=('00FF0000')
cat3=(['None'])

#Color 4
color04=('0000FFFF')
cat4=(['None2'])

#Color 5
color05=('0000FF00')
cat5=(['None3'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly have a customizable config file for each user.  You will need to set it in a specific location that both the program and the user can find.  Commonly this is set to something like (in Windows) `%USERPROFILE%\.myprogname\config.json`.  (I am writing this assuming you are use a json file for you config, though any file type works.)

In your program you can check if the file exists, and if so use it.  Otherwise, use the defaults you have packaged with the executable.

```
import os
import json

user_config = os.environ.get('USERPROFILE') + '\\.myprognam\\config.json'

if os.path.exists(user_config) and os.path.isfile(user_config):
    config_path = user_config
else:
    config_path = 'path/to/default_config.json'

with open(config_path) as fp:
    config = json.load(fp)
```

Comment: IS there a format to the file that I need to follow?

Currently I'm just importing a .py file

Example of one of teh variables
`color01=('00FCC84E')
cat1=(['Speakers','Atlas Mic Stands'])
'

Comment: It is really up to you and how savvy your users are.  json files are easy for a machine to read and decently readable by humans.  I like yaml files a lot as they are very human readable.

Comment: if I want to keep the config file in the same file folder as the exe file, do I just leave out the `('USERPROFILE') + '\\.myprognam\\`    part of it?

Comment: or do I just make user_config = myfilename.json if its in the same directory as teh main file

Comment: You can't really do that because the exe file just unpacks everything to %TEMP% and runs it from there, then wipes it when the program closes.  It knows nothing of where the original exe was located.